# How is a TFT array made?

Tags: lcd, tft, oled, amoled

The more I get into TFT arrays, the more I'm lost.

I know what it does, but how does it look like? Can you split a display and just hold a TFT? Can you buy a TFT on glass, without the rest of the display?

How is it made? It seems to be a circuit, but more like a special one.
I can't find this information anywhere.

I was also wondering if the TFT array design in AMOLEDs can be the same as in LCDs?

Comment: TFT stands for "Thin Film Transistor". It is made using thin film technology.

Comment: A TFT display is a variant of an LCD display, go on Wikipedia and learn how an LCD works, then a TFT LCD. Don't worry yet how it is made. The details of manufacturing processes are often company secret and what you can find is aimed at engineers with an understanding of the basics. So get your basics sorted first.

Comment: They're printed or deposited onto a substrate such as glass or silicon.  You can get glass with TFTs on it that is not a display, but this is less common since displays are the main application of transparent logic circuits.

Comment: Glad to hear that @user1850479 but where can you buy these TFTs on glass? I can't find them anywhere. Does it have a special name?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie TFTs aren't only a part of LCDs. Any active matrix display like **AM**OLED contains a TFT array. I know the basics, so I want to know how is it made. I found some academic research documents, but it is really hard to understand. I'm searching for a human, that would explain to me.

Comment: Trying to buy just individual TFTs is like trying to buy the memory controller of a CPU without getting the rest of the die.  They're not individual components, they're integrated into a larger product like an LCD or an AMOLED. Unless you get lucky and find someone selling factory rejects or something like that, your best option is to take apart an LCD.

Answer (score 1):

They look something like this:
[image]
Source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Cross-section-of-the-gate-line-terminal-in-the-TFT-EPD_fig3_277783771

TFT's are based on a completely different circuit/construction than OLED's.

For one the LED circuits look something like this:

[image]
Source: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Design-of-Organic-TFT-Pixel-Electrode-Circuit-for-Shin-Hwang/ec3b99525caeeee92887e4dcae8731377d37ddb2/figure/5

TFT's look like this:

[image]
Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Color_TFT-LCD_Cells-Schematic.png